# iPhone How to restrict image view from outgoing parent view when rotating, scaling, moving it

Tags: iphone, uiview, bounds

I am writing iPhone app using UIImageView.
I hope a user can rotate, scale, move the image view, but the image view couldn't be out of the parent view bound.
The UIView has a property for doing this?
I consider clipsToBounds property, but it is only for showing/hiding part of the imageview.
I want to restrict it's roataion, scaling, moving inside the parent view's bound.

Comment: it would be much easier to help you if you posted some code.

Comment: Do you mean masking with eg. a photo frame your UIImageView? Or you want to restrict such movements (scale, rotate, move) when part of UIImageView crosses the bounding lines?

Comment: i mean latter, movements.